# How to create retro text effect using Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, text, effects

I would like to achieve a text effect in Inkscape exactly like this:
[image]

Image is from a fast tutorial on how to do it in Illustraotr https://www.instagram.com/p/CIlcivbJFkM/ but I want to create it using Inkscape.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's already an answer. It constructs the tilted view by skewing the text and the apparent thickness is made by layering slightly moved copies of the text. Nothing to blame there if you can accept maybe tens of copies of the same shape. The number of needed copies isn't especially big if screen resolution is enough and you are not going to scale the image bigger.

Another approach is to have multiple copies only as many as there are thick layers. It must start like the previous answer i.e. make a tilted view of the text:

[image]

The text should have a solid fill color but no stroke.

The text stays editable in Inkscape with this transform, but you need an editable path for drawing. Apply Path > Object to Path and Object > Ungroup to get separate ungrouped Bezier curves.

Combine the letters to one compound path by applying Path > Combine. Why: boolean operations later do not work if there are groups and you very likely want to handle the text as one path.

Make a duplicate (=Ctrl+D) and give to it different fill color (=blue). Select the duplicate and shrink it a little by applying Path > Dynamic offset. Drag the handle downwards to get a little smaller version. The copy and the original can be seen in the right:

[image]

Now it's a good moment to open the Objects panel and close (=click the eye)temporarily the shrinked copy to keep it in safe. It disturbs the next phases because it's very easy to  move it accidentally and very difficult to place it again. Beware moving the original. You cannot lock it.

Duplicate the original again. Recolor the copy (=green), move it a little and send it to back to get the back side of the apparent slice thickness:

[image]

It's a good idea to switch off all snaps to get the green version moved. Switch all point snaps ON after the green version is moved.

Draw with the Bezier tool (= the Pen) patches to cover the gaps. You need 2 different which can be copied to cover all gaps. They snap easily at corners, gaps between round curves need the same pieces, but they must be placed visually with high zoom and the snaps switched temporarily OFF or preferably having only snap on path =ON. They would snap easily to wrong points:

[image]

After inserting the patches select all and apply Path > Union. The fill color of the result depends on what's handled recently. I selected red fill color for the union.

Beware moving the union, but make a few differently colored copies. Copy and paste to get surely differently placed copies than the original. Recolor the copies, send them all back and place them. They snap easily if you have point snaps=ON

[image]

Finally make the shrinked copy visible in the Objects panel:

[image]

Comment: +1 Actually this would be the best way to do it in Illustrator too. Adding hundreds of shapes using repeated Transforms as in the tutorial linked to by the OP, is a horrible way to create something like this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the text you want, and apply a stroke (Ctrl+Shift+F). Make the color the bottom color (from the OP teal).
2. Apply a vertical skew transformation (Ctrl+Shift+T), about 4?
3. Duplicate the text (Ctrl+D) and apply a move transformation (-1 horizontal, 1 vertical).
4. Repeat step 3 a few more times until you have attained the desired thickness of teal.
5. Repeat step 3 but change color to the next color (red from OP post) then repeat as many times as you did in 4.
6. Repeat previous steps (3 onward until desired output)

Comment: @user287001 I don't see any unit for transformations (it could be pixels but I wasn't sure), and I don't know how to use the generate from path>interpolate, if you'd like you could answer with a cleaner solution (inkscape v1 interpolate doesn't seem to work)

Comment: Object > Transform dialog has units in Inkscape version 1. Skew is easiest maybe as degrees and move is easiest as pixels because only one pixel stays invisible. Interpolate doesn't work with groups nor texts, it works only with paths. Texts should be converted to paths to use it and multiple letters should be combined (=Path > Combine).  But clone tiling works with all objects. Parameters are tricky for beginners, so I must take my suggestion back. Sorry for disturbing.